# Laravel Eloquent: shifting from a method to another dynamicaly

Tags: laravel, eloquent, builder

Is it possible to shift from a method to another on the fly with the Eloquent builder ?
Something like this:

```
User::whereHas('licences', function($query) use($data) {

  // Query here...
 
if ($foo == $bar) {
   })->get();
}
else {
   })->paginate(15);
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a builder, just assign it to a variable:

```
$query = User::whereHas(...);

$result = $foo == $bar ? $query->get() : $query->paginate(15);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$user = User::where(/* some condition */);

if ($foo == $bar) {
  $result = $user->get();
}
else {
   $result = $user->paginate(15);
}
```